# ActiveX compiled with .NET 3.5 does not install on machine with .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-c++, .net-4.0, mfc, activex

We are developing an ActiveX control targeted for windows 7 and windows 8. We are developing this based on .NET 3.5. But we are facing problems on windows 8 machines that do not have .NET 3.5 enabled. The ActiveX control does not get installed.

Trying to register it manually using `regsvr32` gives the error:

> The module abcd.ocx (name of the binary) failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .dll files.

But the same binary file gets registered successfully when the ".NET 3.5 is activated" from Add/remove programe -> Turn windows features ON feature. There is no difference in the dependency hierarchy in both instances.

Microsoft has a page about the [version compatibility in the .NET framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I could not find anything specific to ActiveX controls. I am not sure if this information is relevant but the ActiveX is developed with Visual C++ and depends on CLR.

My question is: Is it possible to develop and build an ActiveX on .NET 3.5 and run it on a machine that has only .NET 4.0 installed? If yes, it would be great if you can point me to an example or some sample code?

Comment: Is the target machine running full version of .NET Framework or Client Profile? I remember having some problems with .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile. After installing full version my application started to work.

Comment: You need a .config file to tell .NET that it is okay to use the v4 version of the CLR, even though the DLL says it wants the v2 version.  You need one for regsvr32 as well.  This is not very practical.  Much less practical than simply getting the .NET version you want installed.

Comment: @HansPassant does the config file go along with the cab file? I tried to have the config file in the same folder as the ocx and named it abcd.ocx.config but I had the same problem.